# AMD GPU pass-through doesn't work on Windows 7 (even though NVIDIA works)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm

I have a multi-gpu VM setup (Nvidia GTX 970 and AMD RX 6600) with Windows 7, Windows 10, macOS virtual machines. I pass GPU directly to a guest operating system (isolate from host-os and pass them directly to a guest-os).

RX 6600 GPU pass-through works fine on Windows 10 and macOS guest OS but not on Windows 7... even though GTX 970 pass-though to a Windows 7 guest-os works fine on the same machine.

Any ideas why an AMD GPU wouldn't work on a Windows 7 VM but NVIDIA GPU works fine? There's just a black-screen and no input.

I have AMD/NVIDIA drivers installed on guest-VM.

Comment: I think you would need to clarify / define "wouldn't work".

Comment: The AMD is much newer.